# Question regarding order of operations

Tags: fluid-dynamics

(*Fluid Mechanics: Fundamentals and Applications* 4th Edition, Yunus Cengel and John Cimbala, problem 2-88)

[image: Fluid Mechanics Problem]

I am having some trouble with the order of operations. In the case of the below equation:

$4\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}}{1-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}{}}=1$

I do not see how it is true, but in reference to the problem it results from, it just has to be. No matter what I try, I get $4 = 1$. The problem that this originates from is attached as an image. Can someone please let me know whether the problem is with the textbook or with my calculations. This is a simple problem, and yet it is driving me crazy, so I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: You are right and there must be a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I would make sure that you have read understood the result because weather the suggested value is meant to be read as a mixed number or as a 4 times the fraction the result is wrong. So there is either a typo or you misread.

Comment: You should provide the textbook (title and author) from which this image was taken.

Comment: The second sentence at the top of the problem sheet ends abruptly... something is missing, or garbled, maybe.

Comment: The textbook is Fluid Mechanics: Fundamentals and Applications 4th Edition, written by  Yunus Cengel and John Cimbala. The problem is 2-88.

Answer (score 1):

After careful consideration, I believe that the author made an algebraic error.
The author went from

$$\frac{y}{h-y}=\sqrt{\frac{\mu_{\text{lower}}}{\mu_{\text{upper}}}}$$

to

$$y = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\mu_{\text{lower}}}{\mu_{\text{upper}}}}}{1-\sqrt{\frac{\mu_{\text{lower}}}{\mu_{\text{upper}}}}}h$$

I believe that the denominator should be a plus not a negative. Following this logic the answer would be $y=4/3$.

Comment: I understand that typos can be common in textbooks, but I'm quite curious at how common mathematical errors are in textbooks. Is the about the same frequency?

Comment: Errors happen. That's why textbooks sometimes have "errata" sheets.

Comment: And I agree with your conclusions about the algebra. As additional confirmation, your answer is consistent with the earlier equations, while the book's answer is not.